# mscrm import update columnmapping reference attribute

Tags: import, mapping, dynamics-crm, updates

I work on Dynamics 365 and I need to develop a dynamics update of records using the Import Entity.

I manage to make a dynamics import to create record into Dynamics 365 but for update I have that message : 
"This attribute is not mapped as a reference attribute. However, you have included a ReferenceMap for it.  Fix this inconsistency, and then import this data map again."

Well, I don't find any documentation even in SDK even on web even on Microsoft website. I hope to find help from you guys ;)

See my code about columnmapping of my reference ID mapping :

```
Entity colMapping = new Entity(CrmColumnmapping.EntityLogicalName);
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.Fields.SourceAttributeName, dc.Caption);
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.Fields.SourceEntityName, "MySource");
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.Fields.TargetAttributeName, dc.ColumnName);
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.Fields.TargetEntityName, dt.TableName);
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.Lookups.ImportMapId, new EntityReference(CrmImportmap.EntityLogicalName, importMap.Id));
colMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmColumnmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmColumnmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCodeValues.Option1_Process));
colMapping.Id = service.Create(colMapping);

Entity parentLookupMapping = new Entity(CrmLookupmapping.EntityLogicalName);
parentLookupMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Lookups.ColumnMappingId, colMapping.ToEntityReference());
parentLookupMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCodeValues.Option1_Process));
parentLookupMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Fields.LookUpAttributeName, dc.Namespace + "id");
parentLookupMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Fields.LookUpEntityName, dc.Namespace);
parentLookupMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.LookUpSourceCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.LookUpSourceCodeValues.Option2_System));
parentLookupMapping.Id = service.Create(parentLookupMapping);

Entity currentLookUpMapping = new Entity(CrmLookupmapping.EntityLogicalName);
currentLookUpMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Lookups.ColumnMappingId, colMapping.ToEntityReference());
currentLookUpMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.ProcessCodeValues.Option1_Process));
currentLookUpMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Fields.LookUpAttributeName, dc.ColumnName);
currentLookUpMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.Fields.LookUpEntityName, dt.TableName);
currentLookUpMapping.Attributes.Add(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.LookUpSourceCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmLookupmapping.OptionSets.LookUpSourceCodeValues.Option1_Source));
currentLookUpMapping.Id = service.Create(currentLookUpMapping);
```

See my code about import :

```
Entity import = new Entity(CrmImport.EntityLogicalName);
import.Attributes.Add(CrmImport.OptionSets.ModeCode, new OptionSetValue(CrmImport.OptionSets.ModeCodeValues.Option2_Update));
import.Attributes.Add(CrmImport.Fields.Name, "UpdateImport");
import.Id = service.Create(import);
```

If someone know how to map the reference attribute (ex : systemuserid) to manage to make a dynamics update import, it will be appreciated.

Thanks a lot